Custom Airflow Operator
I'm writing a custom airflow operator to wrap up some functionality. Non programmers will be monitoring the DAGs so I want to make the error messages as simple, clean and self explanatory as possible. So far I have not been able to fail a task without raising a big, ugly and pointless stack trace. Below is an example of what I've tried. This is pretty much a copy/paste of the example custom operator from the airflow website except I've added a parameter to trigger a failure. Within the if self.failMe: block is everything I've tried. The only one that seems to be close is context["task_instance"].error(). This give a message ERROR - Recording the task instance as FAILED but then it's followed by INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS and it does indeed mark the task as success. Is there any way to fail the task without adding a stack trace to the logs?
from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator

class HelloOperator(BaseOperator):
    def __init__(self, name: str, failMe: bool, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.failMe = failMe

    def execute(self, context):
        message = f"Hello {self.name}"
        self.log.info(message)
        if self.failMe:
            self.log.error("It failed 3")
            self.log.exception("It failed 3")
            context["task_instance"].error()
            context["task_instance"].state = "failed"
            return "failed"
        return "OK"


I think what you are really looking for is https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/37985 which allows to highlight and color specific rows in the log. Its part of a greater effort to complete https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/37443

That does look like a good option but I would still like to remove the stack trace. Every error doesn't need a stack trace
